# How to use multiple columns to color a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've a dataframe like this;

```py
import pandas as pd 

data = {'K_value':[0.0, 0.012, 0.025, 0.037, 0.050], 'Energy':[-11.957, -11.956, -11.955, -11.952, -11.948], 'Co':[0.122, 0.130, 0.80, 0.523, 0.345 ], 'Mn': [0.072, 0.071, 0.72, 0.065, 0.012],'Fe' : [0.122, 0.129, 0.132, 0.154, 0.122], 'Ge' : [0.384, 0.387, 0.385, 0.382, 0.381]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I can plot first two columns and use the third column as a color and get the plot like this;

```py
df.plot(kind='scatter', x ='K_value', y='Energy', c='Fe', cmap = 'Reds',figsize = (8,6))
```

[image]

Instead of using a single column as a color, I want to use two or more than columns as a color as;

```py
df.plot(kind='scatter', x ='K_value', y='Energy', c=['Fe','Co','Ge'], cmap = ['Reds','Blues','Greens'],figsize = (8,6))
```

However, this code doesn't work. Is there any way I could make this working? It doesn't have to strictly in python, any suggestions will work for me. I just want a plot of first two columns and use other columns as a color for the same plot.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please note that code and data in images are rather unwelcome here. Please post them as text, preferably as minimal code that can run standalone.

Comment: The image of the plot you have posted does not remotely correspond to your code or your data.  Furthermore, all the values in "Fe", "Co", and "Ge" columns are constant and do not take advantage of the color variation offered by cmap. Finally, there is absolutely a way to use multiple colors in cmap, but it is not the way you tried.  The proper way is to use a color spectrum like 'viridis'.

Comment: Thanks @Jay Patel for editing my question.

Comment: @pakpe thanks for your comment. Yes, you're right, the image shown here should not reflect the data shown here, since it was obtained after using whole dataset, and only the first five rows are shown here. In the original dataset, the values in "Fe", "Co", "Mn", "Ge" vary, it was just a coincidence that they came out be a constant for the first five rows. Nevertheless, just to remove any further misunderstanding, I've also changed the values in those columns for the dataset shown here. I hope it is clear now what I'm looking for. Any suggestions do you have for me?